# Purpose of duplicate Maven settings.xml

Tags: java, maven

I'm trying to set up a Maven project and configure my settings.xml file with my tomcat server. However when I was trying to locate this *settings.xml* file I found it in two places:

- `/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.6.3_1/libexec/conf/settings.xml`
- `/Users/me/.m2/settings.xml`

What is the difference between these two files? Are they somehow merged? Should I only update one of them? Should I remove one of them?

Comment: One might be a cache of the other... That said, the first location looks like the place where the actual program is installed. I wouldn't touch that one. The one you should tinker with is either (a) the one in your home folder or (b) one in your specific project that overrides settings in your home folder.

Comment: @DavidBrossard they're not caching each other, but other than that, you're right

Answer (score 3):

The one inside the `/maven/` project folder are the default; that will be picked up by all users of the system. The one in the `/.m2/` folder are specific to your userid.

If you've only got one user in your machine then it might not seem like it makes a difference; but if you have a multi-user system then the default `settings.xml` in your first path will affect all users, while each user has their own `.m2/settings.xml` file.

Generally you should leave configuration in the `/maven/` alone, and make changes to the `/.m2/` contents instead.

Comment: or 3) using something project specific and not even user wide, if project has some special settings.

Comment: @eis Where would you put the project specific settings? Can you just drop a settings.xml in the project root and Maven will pick that up?

Comment: You have to use a mvn flag to do that: `mvn -s ./settings.xml`. It's also possible to put some settings in the pom.xml, although that's not recommended.

Answer (score 2):

See [Settings Reference](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html):

> There are two locations where a `settings.xml` file may live:
>
> - The Maven install: `${maven.home}/conf/settings.xml`
> - A user’s install: `${user.home}/.m2/settings.xm`l
>
> The former `settings.xml` are also called global settings, the latter `settings.xml` are referred to as user settings. If both files exists, their contents gets merged, with the user-specific `settings.xml` being dominant.

Answer (score 1):

In settings.xml you setup your maven configuration rather than the project setup. Both files are merged, but the one in the user's folder is the dominant one.
In this file you can store user/password for a repository, if the system is shared among different users it makes sense to have it in user's home.